# Given a column with sets of data print data that corresponds to group in the adjacent row

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel sheet with two columns of data. The data in the first column is grouped by rows the adjacent column contains some data to be processed.

for example

[image: For example]

What I would like to do is read in the rows in column "A" that have "0" and print the data in column "B" that corresponds to it then move to the second "0.25" group and again print the data, and again move on to the next group. What I have so far is

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\data.xlsx", usecols= "A, B")

x = 0                            
for index, row in df.iterrows():  
   if (row["A"] == x):
     print(row["B"])
     if row["A"] != x:
       x = x + 0.25
       print(row["B"])
```

Which only prints the first "0" group but does not increment and move to the next group. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi there. It's because you have an indentation error. Your `if ... != x` is indented UNDER the `if ... == x`.

Comment: @Stripers247 can you provide the full exact output for clarity? Do you really need to use a loop? Also if the data is already sorted, how is this different from printing just the B values in order?

Comment: @mozway what I ultimately want to do is find the max of each set of data. This part of the code is just a starting point.

Comment: @Stripers247 then `df.groupby('A')['B'].max()`?

Comment: @mozwa Quick question. Is there a way to have the max of each group printed along side every row of that group?

Comment: Yes, see duplicate: `df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max')`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to use `DataFrame.groupby` ?

```py
for value_A, group in df.groupby("A"):
    print(f"{value_A=}")
    print("-" * 80)
    print(group)
    print()
```

Prints:

```
value_A=0.0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     A        B
0  0.0 -0.26680
1  0.0 -0.30345
2  0.0 -0.27020

value_A=0.25
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      A        B
3  0.25 -0.28295
4  0.25 -0.29325
5  0.25 -0.26831
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code provide the solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,0,0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
                 'B': [-0.2668, -0.30345, -0.2702, -0.28295, -0.29325, -0.26831]})


df['B'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['B'] + 0.25 if x["A"] != 0 else x['B'], axis = 1)
     A         B
0   0.00    -0.26680
1   0.00    -0.30345
2   0.00    -0.27020
3   0.25    -0.03295
4   0.25    -0.04325
5   0.25    -0.01831
```